# Using Module pattern

Tags: javascript, module

I'm trying to use Module pattern where I'm getting the error "Cannot read property of undefined". This is because when I'm calling the module method with the module name, it is not able to get the module name and is getting it as undefined. Below is the code:

```
var myModule = (function(){
    var myMethod;
    myMethod = function() {
        alert("callable");
    };

    return {
        anotherMethod: function(){
            myMethod();
        }
    };
}());
```

And below is how I'm calling the module method:

```
myModule.anotherMethod();
```

Please suggest if I'm missing anything.

Cheers,
AW

Comment: Code looks and works fine. Copy and paste it into your console as is and you'll see that it works. This is a working code sample - it can't be debugged or fixed.

Comment: Thanks Adam, it does returns back callable in the pop up but then it returns undefined as well in the console.

Comment: It doesn't "return undefined" it evaluates to undefined in the console because the method call doesn't return anything. This is expected and normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this code working fine in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1347hqr/) and the error, I believe you may not be properly including the file the JavaScript code is in before attempting to execute it. Here is some [more information about the JavaScript module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

```
<script>
var myModule = 
(function(){
    var myMethod;
    myMethod = function() {
        alert("callable");
    };

    return{
        anotherMethod: function(){
            myMethod();
        }
    }; 

}()
);
myModule.anotherMethod();
</script>
```

works perfectly fine and alerts "callable".

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looks like the environment I'm working on is not able to interpret the module pattern for some reasons. I do not need to include the script file separately and the way it is defined within the application it takes it automatically. If I just write JS code in classical format everything in global space, it works fine but when I switch to this, it throws the error.Will try to find that out. But thanks once again.